# Disable auto-lock screen on inactivity Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, display, ubuntu-18.04

I need to disable the auto-screen-lock.

I have tried the following methods as suggested in stack-overflow and other sources.

1. [to disable screen-saver lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048774/disabling-lock-screen-18-04)

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false

2.[to disable idle activation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037740/lock-screen-without-blank-in-18-04)

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false

But even following these recommendations the screen gets auto-locked after sometime when my system is started and when i don't interact with the system.

can someone point me what could be the issue, not able to figure out myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

These things worked out for me.

commands applied for turning off auto-lock and keep display on are following

if below command gives false then set it to true

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

if below command returns true then set it false

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

if below command returns true then set it false

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Comment: Also, try running the commands under `sudo` if without `sudo` will not work.

Comment: Works fine for Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: And disable turn off screen in x minutes: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0;`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20, you would want to run the following from a session already logged in as the user:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```