# Disable Auto Screen Lock on Inactivity with Console Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, display, console, ubuntu-18.04, lock

How do I disable the automatic screen lock on incactivity with the console/bash?
My system: Ubuntu 18.04LTS (VirtualBox)

The commands given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1469437/disable-auto-lock-screen-on-inactivity-ubuntu-18-04) did not work.

Comment: If you just need to get this done, Settings, Power and set Blank Screen to Never.  My Ubuntu 18.04 VM (VMware) screen does not turn off.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

It's necessary to do this with a script, because I have to enroll it to a cluster. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Does this solution work for you (another command line you posted did not work). https://askubuntu.com/questions/719782/change-power-options-for-ubuntu-server-via-terminal

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are power options and screen adjustments in this article below.  I quoted the answer section from the article

> In /etc/systemd/logind.conf, I edited the lines
>
> HandlePowerKey=poweroff ...
>
> HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
>
> to
>
> HandlePowerKey=ignore ...
>
> HandleLidSwitch=ignore
>
> And then reboot the system.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/719782/change-power-options-for-ubuntu-server-via-terminal